# Assign class to tag1 and unassign from tag2 and vice versa with a click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$(".btn1").click(function() { //on each click one class shows and other hides but i cant figure it out
  $(".darktheme").addClass("displaynone");
  $(".whitetheme").removeClass("displaynone");
});
```

```css
.displaynone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">
<span class="darktheme">Dark Theme</span>
<span class="whitetheme displaynone">White Theme</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead:

```js
$(".btn1").click(function() { //on each click one class shows and other hides but i cant figure it out
  $(".darktheme, .whitetheme").toggleClass("displaynone");
});
```

```css
.displaynone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">
<span class="darktheme">Dark Theme</span>
<span class="whitetheme displaynone">White Theme</span>
</button>
```